# Why was my C programming question closed?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

I asked a question on the Main U&L site, and just seen now, that it is closed due to being off topic. To me this question belongs on U&L as I have been working on Ubuntu and found this on my Linux machine.

[Difference Between #include "file.h" and #include <file.h>](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47944/difference-between-include-file-h-and-include-file-h)

The tags I put on, were [c](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) - `gcc` is the compiler, and it compiles programs that are written in C.

Please can someone explain to me why this has happened?

Comment: C, C++ (and GCC btw) aren't specific to Linux or Unix in any way. These include statements have the same semantics on other operating systems types. That's a programming question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [the FAQ](https://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#questions):

> #### What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> If your question is a programming question, requiring knowledge of programming languages other than unix shell scripting languages, ask on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

In this case, it's [already been asked there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)

Comment: For those who didn't know yet, there has been established http://programmers.stackexchange.com as well now. I feel it has been created for the fact that from some point, everything got crammed into SE main site sooner or later, so it started affecting the overview in a negative way.