# What is the current consensus on programming questions?

Tags: discussion, scope, programming

I was originally going to ask a question about this, but found its been asked here a lot already (in numerous variation). Since I've now spent the time digging through meta, I'll document what I've found.

The question: **Are programming questions on-topic?**

Answer (score 4):

When its been directly asked on meta before, there seems to be general agreement that programming questions are, with some exceptions, off topic here:

- [What to do about programming questions](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/576/what-to-do-about-programming-questions)
- [Unix C API calls ontopic?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314/unix-c-api-calls-ontopic)
- [What about questions accepting bash, python, C answers?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/980/what-about-questions-accepting-bash-python-c-answers)
- [Why was my C programming question closed?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1018/why-was-my-c-programming-question-closed)
- [Is shell scripting in perl in range of this site?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248/is-shell-scripting-in-perl-in-range-of-this-site)
- [Please add a reference to Stack Overflow in the site FAQ](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/592/please-add-a-reference-to-stack-overflow-in-the-site-faq)
- [What's better place for questions about "Linux/Unix programming libraries" - Unix.SE or SO?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/868/whats-better-place-for-questions-about-linux-unix-programming-libraries-uni)

Some views are more complex:

- [Shell scripting on-topic?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84/shell-scripting-on-topic)

And some disagree:

- [Is it ok to ask bash language questions?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142/is-it-ok-to-ask-bash-language-questions)

The common exception (also mentioned in the FAQ) is, to quote-mine one of the above, questions that are about "common unix interfaces" and are "essentially language-agnostic."

Answer (score 1):

My guideline is and remains: what type of person might ask the question, be interested in the topic and know the answer?

- Topics for **users and administrators: ask here**.
- Topics for **programmers: ask on Stack Overflow**.

My judgements on [all the cases that have arisen](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1051/what-is-the-current-consensus-on-programming-questions/1052#1052) is based on this guideline. Scripting and text processing with shells, awk, etc., are commonly performed by power users and administrators and therefore are on-topic here. (They are also programming tasks and therefore on-topic on SO as well.) Power users tend to have a working knowledge of some low-level interfaces (through strace, by reading source code that they half-understand to understand why a program is behaving, ...), so questions involving these are also ok here. Questions requiring serious knowledge of an “advanced” programming language (pointers in C, objects in Perl, etc.) are off-topic.

Comment: I assume of course that there is an implicit "Unix and/or Linux" in that guideline somewhere, as we'd surely close a question about Windows Powershell. But that leaves a problem when we get a generic question such as http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50238/calculate-difference-between-two-non-linear-data-sets (which is currently closed). That's something that a non-programmer may want to do, and it can be solved with Unix tools (but so can most things).

Comment: @derobert I don't think that question is off-topic. In the initial version, it was hard to tell what was required, so “not a real question” might have applied. U&L might not be the best site for that question though; this looks like a [stats.se] kind of problem.