# Are questions about how Linux handles specific hardware details on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm not talking about generic hardware questions (e.g. how Linux names a disk device), I'm talking about the handling of very specific hardware details and interactions<sup>1</sup>.

The main problem I see is that the level of knowledge required to answer these questions is the same of somebody *programming* an LKM, or directly the kernel, to control said hardware details and interactions.

I'm not sure if this community accepts such questions as on topic.

---

<sup>1</sup> To contextualise, I'm willing to ask a question about MMIO remapping for the devices behind a node's local PCIe interface on a NUMA system. Particularly the interactions with Source Address Decoders, the SRAT ACPI table and Linux behaviour for cross-node IO requests.

Comment: Parts of that kind of problem might be on topic on EE ?

Comment: @rackandboneman I think EE is too low level, it's more of a Computer Architecture kind of question.

Comment: If you want to include Unix/Linux system programming questions into the scope, It is a request by more than just you. Please keep up the push, because changes always happen from the bottom up, and give some upvote here https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5697/, so that it can become visible again or avoid becoming invisible again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm going to suggest that *programming* questions are in-scope at Stack Overflow. It seems to me that you're "below" the level of the API, which was covered a few years ago in:
[What is the current consensus on programming questions?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1051/what-is-the-current-consensus-on-programming-questions)

Happily, there are several Linux kernel MMIO questions there already, indicating some (potentially larger) community there than here:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blinux-kernel%5D+MMIO+&mixed=0

There is also a Meta Stack Overflow post [Are questions about the internals of the Linux kernel on-topic for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343113/are-questions-about-the-internals-of-the-linux-kernel-on-topic-for-stack-overflo) whose question quotes the linux-kernel tag:

> This tag is for questions about the internals of the Linux kernel itself - particularly about writing code that runs within the context of the kernel (like kernel modules or drivers)

and whose upvoted and accepted Answer says, in part:

> Would it take a programmer to understand answers to this?

where "yes" means on-topic at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you Jeff, very clear and concise.

Answer (score 0):

It’s been established that a question can be on-topic
on multiple Stack Exchange sites simultaneously. 
[Jeff’s answer here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5393/80216#5394) focuses on whether certain questions are
on-topic at Stack Overflow, which is not what this question asks. 
[Gilles’s answer](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1051/80216#1054) to [What is the current consensus
on programming questions?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1051/80216) does not, in my interpretation,
really support Jeff’s answer here. 
Gilles says,

> Power users tend to have a working knowledge of some low-level interfaces
>   (through strace, by reading source code that they half-understand
>   to understand why a program is behaving [sic], …),
>   so questions involving these are also ok here. 
>   Questions requiring serious knowledge of an “advanced” programming language
>   (pointers in C, objects in Perl, etc.) are off-topic.

*This* (meta-)question (i.e., Margaret Bloom’s question)
mentions “a question about MMIO remapping for the devices
behind a node’s local PCIe interface on a NUMA system.” 
This seems to fall under Gilles’s category of “reading source code …
to understand … a program …”
and ***not*** “serious knowledge of an ‘advanced’ programming language
(pointers in C, …)”. 
Therefore, I believe that the answer to Margaret Bloom’s question is
“yes, questions about the behavior / functionality of Linux
***are*** on-topic at U&L.” 
And I believe that Gilles’s answer supports this position.

FWIW, I had this exchange with bwDraco four years ago:

> Is there a SE site on the Linux Kernel? 
>   Do questions about the Linux kernel get answered on Stack Overflow? – G-Man
>
> @G-Man: Unix & Linux – bwDraco

I can’t see it now, because it’s been deleted,
but I had the foresight [to bookmark it](https://superuser.com/questions/968133/why-is-exit-used-in-kernel-module-programming) and keep a copy. 
10K users (on Super User) should be able to verify it.

I’ve been bothered by [Tim Post’s answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343113/3960947#343114)
to [Are questions about the internals of the Linux kernel
on-topic for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343113/3960947)
(again, ***not the same*** as what Margaret Bloom is asking)
ever since I first saw it. 
Sure, “Would it take a programmer to understand answers to this?”
(or even to understand the question itself) is highly relevant. 
But imagine this hypothetical dialog:

> I have cataracts and need eye surgery. 
>   Who should I get to do it?
>
> Well, a surgeon, of course.

Sure, if your choices are an auto mechanic, a surgeon,
and a <s>taxi</s> Uber driver, you should choose the surgeon. 
But, if your choices include a brain surgeon, an eye surgeon
(ophthalmologist), and a heart surgeon, you should pick the eye surgeon.

By the same token, “Would it take a ***Unix system*** programmer
to address this question?” is equally or more important. 
I don’t spend a lot of time at SO, but a glance at [their tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags)
shows a concentration in Java, JavaScript, jQuery, PHP, Python and HTML
— and, yes, C++ and C#. 
C comes in as the 16th tag. 
I don’t know how many SO users are going to be able
to understand a question about a device driver, memory-mapped I/O,
or other kernel code, but it seems like there are going to be
a lot of people there who will be unable to answer such a question. 
Logically, we should have the highest concentration of Unix experts
here at U&L, and so I believe that
questions about details of how Unix behaves are on-topic at U&L.

And,
if we don’t have the highest concentration of Unix experts here at U&L,
that may be because they feel like they’re not wanted here,
because questions in their wheelhouse keep getting kicked out. 
And, IMHO, that would be a shame.

If Stack Overflow has lots of *Unix system* programmers, that’s great. 
But we should encourage such experts to spend time in U&L
by allowing questions *about the **behavior / functionality**
of Unix & Linux* on the U&L site, no matter how low-level they are. 
(Of course questions that are ***about programming***,
like  “What’s the difference between `i++` and `++i`?”, are off-topic here.)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I disagree with your interpretation of my answer. MMIO remapping is not something that a system administrator would configure by tuning kernel parameters, it's something that only a programmer would interact with. A Linux kernel programmer is a programmer. This is not about reading source code to understand the behavior of a program _in order to use this program_, but in order to _extend_ this program. It's a question from a programmer, not a question from a user.